# Chat real time laravel, socket.io + redis

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, chat

Does not display messages in real time, only displayed in one window
Events

```
class Message implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('chat');
    }
}
```

Component chat

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" readonly="">
                    {{ messages.join('\n') }}
                </textarea>
                <hr>
                <input type="text"  class="form-control" v-model="textMessage" @keyup.enter="sendMessage">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
          return{
              messages : [],
              textMessage : ''
          }
        },
        mounted(){
            Echo.channel('chat')
            .listen('Message', ({message}) => {
                this.messages.push(message)
            })
        },
        methods : {
            sendMessage() {
                axios.post('/messages', { body: this.textMessage });
                this.messages.push(this.textMessage);

                this.textMessage = '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The event for sending a message is processed, but the message is not shown in another window.
Shows only where I sent it and that's it, but my interlocutor does not see these messages[image]

Comment: Are you able to webpush any data? Acutally you can see what you sent, because you push the message on client side. Socket.io is on client side, what handle the server side of your websockets (laravelEchoServer? BeyondCode Websockets?, Pusher Websockets?) Are you sure users are both listening on the channel "chat"? Can you log the presence of the users on that channel?

Comment: laravelEchoServer.

Comment: You can manually start laravel-echo-server and the queue. This will log everything into the console and you will be able to see on which channel users are connecting and where the message is dispatch. Cam you check if everything match.

Comment: No, I'm not sure that they are listening to the same chat, how can I make sure that they are listening to the same channel?

Comment: I start server-laravel-echo, but only the event for sending a message will work for me there, but who entered the channel does not show

Comment: So your user are not connecting properly. Can you provide the code where you import Echo and socket.io-client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230302/discussion-between---and-elie-morin).